# Why is my MongoDB exploding in size?

Tags: mongodb

I'm dabbling with MongoDB for a simple application and experience some undesirable behavior. Basically, my collection is composed of many (string, int) tuples, each in average should take less than 64 bytes as a document (including the _id). I have one index on my collection - according to the string.

After adding ~8 million documents, I fail to add any new ones since I hit the 2.5 Gigabyte limit (I have a 32bit OS). It seems like I'm doing something wrong, because I don't see a reason why it should get to that size.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to troubleshoot it?
Obviously, I'll switch to 64bit OS soon, but I want to understand this behavior first.

Update (2):

once the db "fills up", this is the output of the collection stats command:

```
> db.hits.stats()
{
    "ns" : "testdb.hits",
    "count" : 8716619,
    "size" : 611603992,
    "avgObjSize" : 70.16527761509366,
    "storageSize" : 828148736,
    "numExtents" : 21,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 145841408,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 1007568128,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 360636416,
        "article_-1" : 646931712
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

and that's the output of the db stats command:

```
> db.stats()
{
    "collections" : 3,
    "objects" : 8716625,
    "avgObjSize" : 70.16526281674386,
    "dataSize" : 611604284,
    "storageSize" : 828153856,
    "numExtents" : 23,
    "indexes" : 2,
    "indexSize" : 1007568128,
    "fileSize" : 3154116608,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

update (3):
the db files themselves:

```
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  64M 2011-11-14 14:06 testdb.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 128M 2011-11-14 14:06 testdb.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 256M 2011-11-14 14:06 testdb.2
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 512M 2011-11-14 14:06 testdb.3
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 512M 2011-11-14 14:06 testdb.4
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 512M 2011-11-14 14:06 testdb.5
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 512M 2011-11-14 11:20 testdb.6
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup 512M 2011-11-10 10:51 testdb.7
-rw------- 1 mongodb nogroup  16M 2011-11-14 14:05 testdb.ns
```

Comment: What's the output of `db.that_collection.stats()` (append to the question)?

Comment: It has only 1.8M documents. Do you have several collections like this?

Comment: no, it just that it will take me a day to fill it up and opted for a quick response. ok ... more info tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, then tomorrow attach `db.stats()` also :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev here it is. (a) Shouldn't it take only 1.8GB? (b) why is storageSize>size?

Comment: is journaling enabled? if so it will take 2x the memory. what version are you running? what is the specific error message you get once you hit the limit?

Comment: Also remember that your files are stored in blocks on the harddrive. On Windows the default block size for NTFS is 4K, so all files smaller than 4K do consume 4K of storage space anyway. If mongoDB preallocates storage files of 512M size, you may reach the limit pretty fast, if your harddrive is fragmented. I'm not suggesting this causes your problem primarily. But it sure adds to it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your database file sizes? The data itself is 120MB, plus 180MB for 2 indexes, so you rightfully expect that to fit your 2GB limit, but I guess it's mongodb probably doing [aggressive preallocation of reserved space to avoid file system fragmentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+FAQ#DeveloperFAQ-Whyaremydatafilessolarge?) which can be [configured](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space).

Comment: where is your dbpath pointing? what are the file sizes in that folder?